# didSelectRowAtIndexPath in revealViewController

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, swrevealviewcontroller

I'm working with `revealViewController`, and inside this revealViewController I wanted to create a `UITableView` with custom cells according to this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EVJiprvRLoo

and here is my code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
let vcName = identities[indexPath.row]
let viewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(vcName)
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController!, animated: true)
}
```

I'm using a storyboard, but I didn't get any issues, but it's not working.

I also tried to make a push segue to that view controller, but then my navigationViewController disappears, and I think it's would be easier by using code.

Sorry if my question is not accurate, but hope you can understand it.

Many Thanks.

Comment: Have you set the viewController identifier name in storyboard?

Comment: Specifically, you need to set the Storyboard ID in the Identity Inspector.

Comment: yes i have set the identifier in storyboard, but it's not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `self.navigationController?` is nil. You should do something like this:

```
let vcName = identities[indexPath.row]
let viewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(vcName)
let navVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController:viewController)
```

and then set front view controller by method of `SWRevealViewController`:

`- (void)pushFrontViewController:(UIViewController *)frontViewController animated:(BOOL)animated;`

`self.revealViewController.pushFrontViewController(navVC, animated:true)`

Comment: Thanks, that was my problem, I really appreciate your help.  You're awesome ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have to push to the RevealController Not to the ViewController